# What is the meaning of "know this far forth"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across this sentence in "The Tempest" by Shakespeare:

> Know this far forth

This is Prospero's reply to question of Miranda in which she asks him why he raised that sea storm? How should I interpret it?

Comment: To read Shakespeare, you need one of the annotated versions. There are many in paperback.

Comment: Frankly, if you're learning English, you shouldn't read Shakespeare as it is nowhere near modern English in both grammar and vocabulary. So this kind of question does not seem to fit ELL SE.

Comment: Please cite what comes BEFORE this. I don't want to go and look it up.

Comment: First, get the right quote from: the searchable Shakespeare and quote it accurately.

Answer (score 1):

The text should be "know *thus* far forth." Prospero is basically saying that she should listen to what he's about to say so that she will remember it in future;
"Know" - understand, learn
"thus" - what I'm about to say
"far" - for a long time
"forth" - from now.

Comment: While this is true, you should provide a link to a source that shows this to be true. Otherwise, you're stating this without any evidence.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica We aren't even supposed to be explaining text so unless this is closed, I don't see that it makes any difference.